How to get the row-wise median over several columns of a PostgreSQL table?
My question is quite similar to this, but instead of the mean, I need to find the median value over different columns of a row (in order to identify some outliers).
Suppose I have the following table:
X   Y    Z
-------------
6   3    3
5   6    NULL
4   5    6
11  7    8

What I need is:
MEDIAN
-------------
3
5 or 5.5
5
8

In case of an even number of non-NULL elements, the median could be just one of the central values or the average. I don't care so much about that, any version would be fine for me.
Ideally, I would like to define this solution as a PostgreSQL-function, so that I can simply use it like GREATEST/LEAST, but any idea would be appreciated.
Edit: It would be great if the table/column names would not be hard coded within the function, so one could call it like median(x,y,z), but also with any other columns (and number of columns). ...so that it could be used with median(a,b,c,d,e) as well.

As a function, using an array and sorting it with the extension intarray, it could be done like this:
create extension intarray; /*to be able to use sort()*/

create or replace function median() returns setof decimal as $$ 
declare 
    r record;   
begin
    for r in    
        select (sort(array_remove(array[x,y,z], null))) array_sorted, 
        array_length(array_remove(array[x,y,z], null), 1) as len 
        from stats order by id
    loop 
        if mod(r.len, 2) != 0 then
            return next r.array_sorted[(r.len+1)/2];
        else 
            return next (r.array_sorted[(r.len+1)/2] + r.array_sorted[(r.len+1)/2+1]) / 2::decimal;
        end if;
    end loop;   
end; 
$$ language plpgsql;

fiddle to test here
Another version, not hardcoded and using a variable number of arguments
create or replace function median(variadic arr integer[]) returns decimal as $$ 
declare 
    array_sorted int[];
    len int;
begin
    array_sorted = sort(array_remove(arr, null));
    len = array_length(array_sorted, 1);     
    if mod(len, 2) != 0 then
        return array_sorted[(len+1)/2];
    else 
        return (array_sorted[(len+1)/2] + array_sorted[(len+1)/2+1]) / 2::decimal;
    end if; 
end; 
$$ language plpgsql;


select id, median(a,b,c,d,e) from stats order by id;

and the fiddle to test here

Thanks, this looks already very good. Do you think it would be possible to write this without hard-coding the column names (and even the number of columns)? ...as explained in my edit of the question?

@Ludwig I think that would be possible, maybe I'll give it a try later.

Your second version without the hardcoded columns is almost exactly what I needed. Only thing was that I had double columns in my real-world application. So I defined it for input (variadic arr anyarray) and used the more universal sort algorithm from this post. Thanks, I mark this as solved!

Flipping it to jsonb and then back so as to use the percentile_cont() function is a lazy way to do this:
select t.*, percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by e.v::int)
  from mytest t
       cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(t)) e(k,v)
 group by t.x, t.y, t.z;

Working fiddle

Thank you, this looks promising, even if I don't really understand, why you use jsonb and how this works exactly. Does this kind of "transpose" the table (making columns to rows and vice versa)?

@Ludwig  Flipping it to JSONB and back transposes the columns to rows so that you can use the built-in function.  About your "vice versa":  There is no way to go from rows to columns without knowing beforehand what columns you want in the result.
